# items from listview to which field and how?

Tags: java, android, android-listview, textview, android-button

I have 2 list view filled with items in it. I want to take those items, and display them in something like this, for example:

item1+item2+item3

all separated with "+". However, I don't know what I should put this(textview, listview?) considering I need to be able to retrieve those elements (item1+item2+item3) to another (text or listview?) after. And also I'm not quite sure of how to add the items from that listview to another field separated by a "+"? I'm a beginner in java/android.

Comment: you should always try to have a single origin of data. That imply not putting data in the ui and fetching it back, but fetching it from where you got it the first time.

Comment: what do you mean? I have a listview filled with item1,item2 and item3.I want to take those items and display them in something(the point of my question) like this :items1+items2+items3 and how to do that

Comment: my comment was addressing that part `I need to be able to retrieve those elements`